# Azure: Use App Gateway for Custom B2C Domain instead of Front Door

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door

I have an Azure Front Door providing a custom domain for Azure AD B2C.

Is it possible to use an Azure Application Gateway for that purpose instead?

It seems like [the main difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq#what-is-the-difference-between-azure-front-door-and-azure-application-gateway-) is just the global nature of FD, but I'm not sure if that's important to this scenario, or if there is anything else specific to the implementations of FD vs AGW that would make a difference.

> While both Front Door and Application Gateway are layer 7 (HTTP/HTTPS) load balancers, the primary difference is that Front Door is a global service whereas Application Gateway is a regional service. While Front Door can load balance between your different scale units/clusters/stamp units across regions, Application Gateway allows you to load balance between your VMs/containers etc. that is within the scale unit.

[Based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69165821/use-azure-ad-b2c-custom-domain-without-azure-front-door) I suspect this answer is no, but there was no supporting reference and I'm wondering if the App Gateway also being an Azure service makes a difference.

Comment: What’s the purpose?

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Our infra is all routed through an AGW already. Adding a Front-Door just to facilitate a custom domain on B2C is extra technical and cost overhead that feels entirely unnecessary if the FD & AGW serve virtually the same function. So the overall purpose is cutting down on additional cost & technical complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot onboard a custom domain in B2C without Azure Front Door.We can add custom domain to azure ad directly but adding custom domain to azure ad B2C tenant is not available directly.

You can submit your feedback here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/feedback/

Comment: This is what I assumed, which is too bad. Do you know of any documentation that states that explicitly?